# Python Dash Plotly Websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I'm a n00b with Dash and I'm trying to update a DashTable from websocket feeds.
The code appears to work when there aren't too many feeds, but once there are, Chrome starts spamming my server with fetch requests (from dash_update_component)

Is there any way to make this more performant ?

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import json
import pandas as pd

from dash import callback, Dash, dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash_extensions import WebSocket

symbols = ["BTCUSDT"]
columns = ["symbol", "bid_volume", "bid_price", "ask_volume", "ask_price"]


def create_data():
    data = {}
    for col in columns:
        if col == "symbol":
            data[col] = symbols
        else:
            data[col] = [None] * len(symbols)
    return data


df = pd.DataFrame(data=create_data())

# Create example app.
app = Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns], id='tbl', editable=True),
    dcc.Input(id="input", autoComplete="off"), html.Div(id="message"),
    WebSocket(url="wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/", id="ws")
])

# Write to websocket.
@app.callback(Output("ws", "send"), [Input("input", "value")])
def send(value):
    sub_msg = {
        "method": "SUBSCRIBE",
        "params": [],
        "id": 1
    }
    for ins in symbols:
        sub_msg["params"] += ([f"{ins.lower()}@bookTicker"])
    return json.dumps(sub_msg, indent=0)


# Read from websocket.
@app.callback(Output('tbl', 'data'), [Input("ws", "message")])
def on_feed(message):
    if "data" not in message:
        return dash.no_update
    else:
        data = json.loads(message["data"])
        print(data)
        symbol = data["s"]
        row_idx = df.index[df['symbol'] == symbol].tolist()[0]
        df.loc[row_idx, columns] = [symbol, data["B"], data["b"], data["a"], data["A"]]
        return df.to_dict('records')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image: Chrome debugger]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do to improve performance is to convert your callbacks into [clientside callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks):

```
symbols = ["ETHBUSD", "BNBUSDT", "BTCUSDT"]

# ...

app.clientside_callback(                                                                      
    """                                                                                       
    function(value) {                                                                         
        const symbols = ['ETHBUSD', 'BTCUSDT', 'BNBUSDT']                                             
        const subMsg = {                                                                      
            'method': 'SUBSCRIBE',                                                            
            'params': [],                                                                     
            'id': 1                                                                           
        };                                                                                    
        for (const ins of symbols) {                                                          
            subMsg.params.push(`${ins.toLowerCase()}@bookTicker`);                            
        }                                                                                     
                                                                                              
        return JSON.stringify(subMsg);                                                        
    }                                                                                         
    """,                                                                                      
    Output("ws", "send"),                                                                     
    Input("input", "value"),                                                                  
    prevent_initial_call=True                                                                 
)                                                                                             
                                                                                              
app.clientside_callback(                                                                      
    """                                                                                       
    function(message, tableData) {                                                            
        if (message === undefined) {                                                          
            return window.dash_clientside.no_update;                                          
        }                                                                                     
                                                                                              
        data = JSON.parse(message['data']);                                                   
        if (data === undefined) {                                                             
            return window.dash_clientside.no_update;                                          
        }                                                                                     
                                                                                              
        const newTableData = tableData;                                                       
                                                                                              
        row = newTableData.find(row => row.symbol === data['s']);                             
                                                                                              
        if (row !== undefined) {                                                              
            row['bid_volume'] = data['B'];                                                    
            row['bid_price'] = data['b'];                                                     
            row['ask_volume'] = data['a'];                                                    
            row['ask_price'] = data['A'];                                                     
        }                                                                                     
                                                                                              
        return tableData;                                                                     
    }                                                                                         
    """,                                                                                      
    Output("tbl", "data"),                                                                    
    Input("ws", "message"),                                                                   
    State("tbl", "data"),                                                                     
    prevent_initial_call=True                                                                 
)
```

> Clientside callbacks execute your code in the client in JavaScript rather than on the server in Python.

https://dash.plotly.com/performance

If you look at the network tab you can see that no websocket related requests are made anymore now.

In this case we're still updating the table for every valid message coming in. You might also want to limit this by using a [`dcc.Interval`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval):

```
dcc.Interval(id="interval", interval=500) # interval fires every 500 ms

# ...

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(nIntervals, message, tableData) {
        if (message === undefined) {
            return window.dash_clientside.no_update;
        }

        data = JSON.parse(message['data']);
        if (data === undefined) {
            return window.dash_clientside.no_update;
        }

        const newTableData = tableData;

        row = newTableData.find(row => row.symbol === data['s']);

        if (row !== undefined) {
            row['bid_volume'] = data['B'];
            row['bid_price'] = data['b'];
            row['ask_volume'] = data['a'];
            row['ask_price'] = data['A'];
        }

        return tableData;
    }
    """,
    Output("tbl", "data"),
    Input("interval", "n_intervals"),
    State("ws", "message"),
    State("tbl", "data"),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
```

You can experiment with adjusting the interval. A lower interval makes result are more "real time"/accurate, but a higher interval means less updates that need to be performed.